# Is there any way to create a dropdown out of mat-list in angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, dropdown

I've created a list in angular using mat-list. Here's my code:

```
  <mat-list style="display: inline-grid;">
      <mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of item">
        <mat-checkbox
        [(ngModel)]="item.checked"
        [disabled] = "item.disabled"            
        >{{ item.name }}</mat-checkbox>
      </mat-list-item>
  </mat-list>
```

Right now, there's a list being displayed. Is there any way I could get all these items in the form of a dropdown?

Comment: you want to have this list with checkbox but using a dropdown instead?

Comment: Yes, basically I want to have a button and on clicking it, there should be a dropdown that contains all these elements

Answer (score 0):

Check the `Select` component from Angular Material [link](https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples)

Here's a basic example:

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
  <mat-select>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

```js
interface Food {
  value: string;
  viewValue: string;
}

@Component({...})
export class SelectOverviewExample {
  foods: Food[] = [
    {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
    {value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
    {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'},
  ];
}
```

Comment: I tried using the select component. The problem with this is that I can't dynamically check/uncheck elements.

Comment: @JoshuaFernandes Did you check the first example in the `EXAMPLES` tab? it uses checkboxes